# Detecting a cycle in a path between 2 vertices

Tags: algorithm, graph

I'm interested in finding if there's a cycle in some path between two given vertices, S and T in a directed graph G.

i.e return "true" if there **exists** at least one path between S and T where there is a cycle, in a time complexity of `O(|V|+|E|)`. I just want some algorithm in pseudo-code.

I wanted to use Kosaraju-Sharir's algorithm, the problem is that even if S and T are in the same strongly connected component the answer is not necessarily "true", in case the cycle only starts from T and the path from S to T is simple.

Thank you.

Comment: What counts as a cycle? Should it go through any edge at most once?

Comment: if both are in the same strongly connected component the answer should be "True" since from some middle node C on the path from S to T you can reach back to S and that's a cycle

Comment: If the `S,T` are in same SCC, then there is a path `S->...->T`, and `T->...->S` (definition of SCC). Then, let's look at the path `S->...->T->...->S->...->T`. This path contains a cycle.

Comment: However, the other way around is not true, look at the graph `{S,a,b,T},  {(S,a), (a,b), (b,a), (a,T)}`. There is a cycle in some path between `S` to `T`: `S->a->b->a->T`, but the SCCs are `{S}, {a,b}, {T}`.

Comment: Clarification needed: do you actually want a path from S to T that contains a cycle *that doesn't contain either S or T*? Asking because without the added condition the example with strongly connected component does not seem to make sense.\